# Difference in item drop between old and new characters

Tags: diablo-iii

I played through Reaper of Souls with the new crusader character and was impressed by the yellow items that dropped. I regularly found fittings rare items.

I then went on to play Act V with my wizard, which I had started in Diablo 3 prior to the extension and I found that the items that dropped were not as interesting. It took quite some time till I was able to replace my armor with new items - they just weren't that good.

So my question: Is there a difference if you play with an "old" character or a new one? Is it worth it to start a new wizard and play through the game again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature (that I have ever heard of); character creation date should not affect the quantity or quality of your drops.

It is possible that your Wizard was simply better geared (due to past availability of the Auction House, and time spent at the old level cap getting drops), and that therefore the rares that dropped were less impressive in comparison. Whereas your Crusader, being new, only had access to dropped items, and thus was continually getting better drops.

And of course, random chance could always be a factor. All drops are determined by random rolls, and sometimes randomness can feel very streaky.